# Empty response body on retrofit call

Tags: android, post, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a app whos call a service POST (postman test) and get some information from that call.

My retrofit initializer:

```
class RetrofitInitializer {

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://bank-app-test.herokuapp.com/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    fun loginApiContract() : LoginApiContract{
        return retrofit.create(LoginApiContract::class.java)
    }
}
```

the interface:

```
interface LoginApiContract {

    @POST("login")
    fun login() : Call<UserAccount>

    @GET("statements")
    fun getStatements()
}
```

and finally the call:

```
val call = RetrofitInitializer().loginApiContract().login()

call.enqueue(object: Callback<UserAccount> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserAccount?>?,
    response: Response<UserAccount?>?) {
        response?.body()?.let {
            val myUserAccount: UserAccount = it
            loginView.doLogin(myUserAccount)
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserAccount?>?,
    t: Throwable?) {
        Log.e("onFailure error", t?.message)
    }
})
```

I got response code 200, but response body is empty.

This is my postman response:

```
{
"userAccount": {
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "Jose da Silva Teste",
    "bankAccount": "2050",
    "agency": "012314564",
    "balance": 3.3445
},
"error": {}
}
```

and this is my model:

```
class UserAccount constructor(var userId: Int, var name: String, var bankAccount: String, var agency: String, var balance: Double){

    init{

        this.userId = userId
        this.name = name
        this.bankAccount = bankAccount
        this.agency = agency
        this.balance = balance
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: use a data class for UserAccount: this is much less verbose because it doesn't need a constructor and it generates equals/hashcode functions. You can call `.copy(` on data classes, after which you should have no problems with keeping the values immutable (`val`).

Comment: my onResponse is called before i send the answer by postman. I think its other problem.

Comment: @FlávioCosta have you log the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found!

Its a problem with my postman. For any reason my AVD cant access the mock server. now i solve my problem with a simple restful api node.js.

Thx for the help guys.

Answer (score -1):

Your response contains elements named "userAccount" and "error". Your UserAccount class has neither which is causing the issue. Therefore, use Retrofit with a class like this:

```
data class UserResponse(val userAccount: UserAccount, val error: BackendError)
```

Comment: I do that and i got the same problem, but now i have 2 empty objects. UserAccount and BackendError